# J1939 ,9pin Deutsch diagnostic connector

Tags: resistors, termination

I am a novice,in this area Sorry!I have no communication/ connection to a excavator as in the above title
My later model machine I can connect no problems.
Between the pins for Can High and Can low I have 16.92 ohms,
I believe it should be about 50-60 ohms?
I have good earth and I have ignition voltage .
Would this resistance be enough  to cancel out diagnostic communication through can bus?
It has no effect on machine ,but in reading of faults ,no can do!
Any thoughts and solutions very welcome.
Thanks ever so much
Regards Mo

Comment: Please properly structure your question; add empty lines between logical sections (*paragraphs*). Avoid "thank you", "regards" and "sorry" phrases, as they are a) meaningless and b) just unnecessarily increase the length and complexity of your question. I just add meaningless phrases now to help you understand. Sorry! Thank you for reading. All this means so much to me; it's not the first comment I write, but I still wonder at times. Hope you have a great day. I'm not sure what I could've done to make this comment more on-point and easy to read. Bear with me! Best regards, My name is Marcus.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the resistance between CAN Hi and Low should be 60 ohms.  Each end of the bus should have a 120 ohm resistor, and since there should be only 2, their parallel resistance should be 60 ohms.
Have you made sure you are measuring resistance across the correct pins on your diagnostic connector?  I believe this is the connector you have:

[image: 9 Pin Deutsch Diagnostic Connector]

So make sure the resistance between C an D (CAN Hi and Lo for j1939 bus) is 60 ohms.  If it really is much lower, there is an electrical problem.  Your CAN bus may be frayed somewhere and shorting to Ground or something.  CAN communication relies on having the correct resistance between CAN Hi and Lo so it's likely your j1939 bus won't work until you get that issue resolved.